# Comparing OSGi Test Frameworks

Tags: osgi, integration-testing

I am looking into integration testing frameworks for OSGi applications. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881/osgi-testing), I've started looking into two main options: [PaxExam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam) and [SpringDM](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html). Now from where I'm standing, these frameworks look like they do the same thing: start an OSGi framework, inject your bundles, dynamically deploy your tests to a bundle, and then run that in the OSGi container. Sound right?

Does anyone have any practical experience using one or both of these tools? Which would you recommend? Can you specify any important difference between these two frameworks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pax Exam is more flexible. It's possible to run tests for various combinations of OSGi Container-Version (PaxRunner option). Also possible to run an OSGi container from class path (Native runner = SpringDM).

Regards,
Dmytro

Comment: +1 Dmytro, PaxExam is fantastic though it's a little hard to workout from the documentation what's still applicable (now on version 2.4).  That said the ops4j pax community are very responsive on mailing lists and jira.  Well worth the initial learning curve IMO.